# Json validator validates successfully for any string inputs

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

Root Schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "properties": {
        "deviceId": {
            "description": "Unique ID of the device of type UUIDv4",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid"
        }
    },
    "required": ["deviceId"]
}
```

Json validation properly reports error for below below input, as uuid is invalid

```
{
    "deviceId" : "410c75b4"
}
```

However the validator does not report any error, if below are the inputs.

```
Input Json Data:
""
"1234"
0
```

As per my understanding root schema specifically says that `deviceId` is the `required` json input, but still json validator successfully validates empty string, random string or some number against the json schema.

Python code

```
    try:
        validate(instance=jsoninput, schema=rootschema, format_checker=jsonschema.FormatChecker())
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Validation failed: {err}')
        return False
```

Also tested here https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: I would also add a line "type": "object" to the schema to make it clear it is an object with properties.

Comment: @Clemens even if I add `"type": "object"` or `"type" : ["string", "object"]`, it still has the same behavior.
I corrected the deviceID, updateId mistake

Comment: I have no further idea why the uuid format doesn't seem to be checked as it should be in all cases. Maybe asking directly at the project pages?

Answer (score 1):

Most JSON Schema keywords apply only when given a certain type of data. In this case, `properties` and `required` only apply if the JSON instance is an object, otherwise they are ignored. So, if you try to validate the instance `"foo"` against this schema, it would be the same as validating against the empty schema (`{}`) and it would pass.

To fix this problem, you need to include `"type": "object"`. This will make the schema fail as expected if the JSON instance isn't an object.

It's also worth noting that `format` does not validate by default. By default, it's just an annotation. So, if you expect your JSON instance to be invalid if it doesn't include a proper UUID, you'll need to configure your validator to enable `format` validation.

Comment: Hi @Jason, actually I tried adding type as object as well but it still passes. And in implementation I have added a formatter

Comment: @Daemon If you're validating a string against a schema with `type: "object"` and it passes, the library you're using is very broken or you're not using it correctly.